# GPU is not detected in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, windows-server-2019

I am using Tensorflow on Windows, and I am trying to use my GPU. But Tensorflow seems unable to detect my GPU.

I created a [Python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and installed Python (3.8) and TensorFlow. My environment is:

- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 GPUs (10+10)
- Processor: Intel Xeon Gold 6348 CPU @ 2,60GHz, 3.50GHz
- RAM: 512 GB
- NVIDIA driver version=511.65
- CUDA Version: 11.6 Cudnn: 9.0.0 (I think it is wrong, I need to downgrade it to 8.9?)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

When I type

```
>nvidia-smi

>nvcc-V
```

both work. However, when I try to use:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", 
    len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

I get the output:

> Num GPUs Available: 0

I do not understand. Also, the link does not provide updated Cuda and Python versions in Windows. Do I need to downgrade everything? Cuda and drivers as well? How do I fix it?

Even after downgrading the NVIDIA drivers and CUDA to 460.82 and 11.2 *(**This failed**; it says it is not compatible, had to install 11.6 again) (according to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)) it does not work.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

### Tensorflow no longer supports GPUs

Tensorflow [no longer supports GPU on Windows:](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) <sup>[archive](https://archive.vn/mbymj)</sup>:

From the Tensorflow web-site:

> **Caution:** TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install [TensorFlow in WSL2](https://tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2), or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the [TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-)

You can install the older version [using:](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-gpu-not-working-on-windows/13120/8)

```
>pip install tensorflow==2.10
```

The idea was that they were tired of supporting GPUs and CUDA, so they created a version of Tensorflow that supports "plugins". This way different hardware manufacturers could supply their own plugin.

### Microsoft DirectML plugin for Tensorflow

In 2021, Microsoft created a Tensorflow plugin that allows you to use any DirectML-compatible GPU or hardware device:

- **GitHub**: [TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin)

This way you could use your GPU with Tensorflow again.

### Microsoft abandoned DirectML plugin

On October 24, 2023, Microsoft abandoned DirectML:

- Issue #369: [Support for python 3.11, support for tf 2.13, is this project abandoned?](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin/issues/369)

Tensorflow no longer runs on Windows, and cannot be used by Windows users.